# how to display a error message when the user didn't choose an item on DropdownMenuItem?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I try to collect data in firestore from my Flutter app. With the following code: my question is how to display a error message when the user didn't choose an item on DropdownMenuItem?

```
 body: Form(
          key: _formKeyValue,
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButton(
                    items: _specialite
                        .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                              child: Text(
                                value,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              value: value,
                            ))
                        .toList(),
                    onChanged: (selectedAccountType) {
                      print('$selectedAccountType');
                      setState(() {
                        medicalType = selectedAccountType;
                      });
                    },
                    value: medicalType,
                    isExpanded: false,
                    hint: Text(
                      'choisissez la spécialité',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
             
              ....
              ....
```

i used this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59746301/15400156  but nothing displayed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the first menu item called "Select xxx", which is also the default item (index 0), then you can check the index when the user hit "Submit" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in different ways.Remove `value` property from `DropDownButton` and initialize `medicalType` with `String medicalType;`. Then on submit button press, check if `medicalType` is null or not. Below is the full code.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<String> _specialite = ["abc", "def", 'ghi'];
  String medicalType;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Form(
//           key: _formKeyValue,
      child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                DropdownButton(
                  items: _specialite
                      .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(
                              value,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            value: value,
                          ))
                      .toList(),
                  onChanged: (String selectedAccountType) {
                    print('$selectedAccountType');
                    setState(() {
                      medicalType = selectedAccountType;
                    });
                  },
//                     value: medicalType,
                  isExpanded: false,
                  hint: Text(
                    'choisissez la spécialité',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (medicalType == null) {
                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text("please choose medical type")));
                  }
                },
                child: Text("submit"))
          ]),
    ));
  }
}
```